# I want to close my question, why can't I do that?

Tags: support

I've come to realize that StackExchange is not the right place for my question and I want to close it (I have voted close already). I don't want to delete it though, because I think the responses and reactions to my question are valuable nonetheless.

Thing is, I can't find an option to actively close the question. Is it intended that I can't do that, or am I just too blind?

Comment: It seems borderline, but not enough where I'd justify closing it myself. It's a good question. It also has 4 of the 5 close votes needed. You could jump into [chat] and make a case for that last close vote, assuming you *really* feel strongly about it being closed. A lot of our users hang out in chat. Hope this helps!

Comment: I totally get it. I just thought, I might not be doing it right. I didn't feel that strong about closing it and it does attract some great answers now. At first I just felt like it was actually the wrong place to answer it and therefore thought I'd close it. @enderland's point about the question belonging to the community to some extend is a great way of seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes 5 votes from the community (or one from a moderator) to close a question. You can vote to close your own question, but that's just one of the needed votes.

When a question has close votes (or has been flagged for closure by a user without enough reputation to actually vote to close), it appears in the "Close Votes" review queue.

Comment: So, it's intended that I can't close my own questions when I feel like it. Thank you!

Comment: @CMW keep in mind "your question" is not quite accurate since this site somewhat functions like Wikipedia - you might originate it but eventually it belongs to the community to some extent

Comment: That is a very good point, @enderland. My intent wasn't at all to question the practice as such, though, but rather figure out if this is intended behavior or if I'm doing something wrong.